# Como descobrir a versão do PHP de um projeto laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Como descobrir a versao php do projeto laravel, tem algum comando no cmd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para visualizar de um jeito rápido, pode editar o seu arquivo index.php  dentro da pasta public colocando no inicio isso:

```
<?php
     phpinfo();
```

É simples mas resolveu seu problema!

Answer (score 2):

Verifique dentro do arquivo `composer.json`, lá trás a versão que foi criado o projeto e os requisitos

```
"php": ">=5.6.4"
```

Answer (score 1):

Abra uma tag em algum blade.php, como o index.blade.php, na pasta public e digite

```
 <?php
     phpinfo();
 ?>
```

Aqui já testei isso, e funciona abs!